# Resolving a component implementation

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have followed [this](http://flexscript.wordpress.com/2008/09/22/flex-creating-custom-validators/) tutorial to implement an IP Validator over a TextInput. But, I have not been able to resolve following error for some hours.

**Error:**

```
Could not resolve <flexScript:IPAddressValidator> to a component implementation.    MasterTabNavigator.mxml /XflowGUI/src/view
```

**Code:**

*MasterTabNavigator.mxml:*

```
<mx:TabNavigator xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                 xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                 xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                 xmlns:flexScript="flexScript.*" >

<s:TextInput id="txtServerIP" width="200"/>
<flexScript:IPAddressValidator source="{txtServerIP}" property="text"/>
</mx:TabNavigator>
```

*flexScript package: (Exact copy of the code given [here](http://flexscript.wordpress.com/2008/09/22/flex-creating-custom-validators/)*

```
package flexScript
{
    import mx.validators.ValidationResult;
    import mx.validators.Validator;


    public class IPAddressValidator extends Validator {

        public function IPAddressValidator() {
            // Call base class constructor.
            super();
        }

        override protected function doValidation(value:Object):Array {
            // create an array to return.
            var ValidatorResults:Array = new Array();
            // Call base class doValidation().
            ValidatorResults = super.doValidation(value);       
            // Return if there are errors.
            if (ValidatorResults.length > 0)
                return ValidatorResults;

            if (String(value).length == 0)
                return ValidatorResults;

            var RegPattern:RegExp = /\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b/;
            var a:Array = RegPattern.exec(String(value));
            if (a == null)
            {
                ValidatorResults.push(new ValidationResult(true, null, "IPAddress Error","You must enter an IP Address"));
                return ValidatorResults;
            }
            return ValidatorResults;
        }
    }
}
```

I will be glad if someone can spot the mistake I have made. Also, I don't have two components named same as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152679/could-not-resolve-to-a-component-implementation) post where the inquirer had a very similar issue.

Comment: Have you got the IPAddressValidator in a folder under src called flexscript? Its more than likely just a folder structure problem

Comment: Yes. Path of the class is: src > flexscript > IPAddressValidator.as

Comment: And, the file in which I am trying to access it is lying at: src > view > MasterTabNavigator.mxml

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put your IPAddressValidator in flex:Declarations part...? Should be there.

Comment: @baltusaj did you try out my suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix. I ran your code, same problem as you, so changed the `flexScript` package name to `flexScript1` (must be some kind of reserved word), and added the IPValidator to the declarations tag and it worked perfect. Needed both changes for it to work.

```
    <fx:Declarations>
        <flexscript1:IPAddressValidator source="{txtServerIP}" property="text"/>
    </fx:Declarations>
```

Here's the full code which runs for a Flex 4.5 web app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"                
               xmlns:flexscript1="flexscript1.*">

    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Define the PhoneNumberValidator. -->
        <flexscript1:IPAddressValidator id="pnV" 
                                 source="{phoneInput}" property="text"
                                 />
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:TextInput id="phoneInput" keyUp="{phoneInput}"/>
    <s:TextInput id="focusOut"/>

</s:Application>
```

Also, have a look at the following link for validation as you type: 
[Flex - number validation, wont remove red glow if click focus? (example provided)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564815/flex-number-validation-wont-remove-red-glow-if-click-focus-example-provided)